# How to call a C DLL from a VBA application and return an array?

Tags: c, arrays, vba

I'm developing a a VBA application which writes and reads a serial port through a C DLL. In the code below I have managed to return a value into the VBA code in the form of a string.

What I want to do is call the function in the DLL and have the returned value inserted into an array. I also don't want to use the split function to parse the string into and array after I get it back as my implementation of VBA does not have access to that function.

C DLL Function

```
void FAR PASCAL RxReadResponse(char* Response)
{
    char TempChar; //Temporary character used for reading
    char SerialBuffer[100];//Buffer for storing Rxed Data
    DWORD NoBytesRead;
    int i = 0;
    char buf [20];
    char bufFull [256];
    long num;
    long streamLenght;
    do
     {
          ReadFile( hComm,           //Handle of the Serial port
                    &TempChar,       //Temporary character
                    sizeof(TempChar),//Size of TempChar
                    &NoBytesRead,    //Number of bytes read
                    NULL);


          SerialBuffer[i] = TempChar;// Store Tempchar into buffer
          sprintf(buf,"%x",TempChar& 0xFF);
          strcat(bufFull, buf);

          if(i==0)
           {
              num = (int)TempChar;
              streamLenght = num + 4;
           }

          i++;
     }
    while (i < streamLenght);

    lstrcpy (Response, bufFull);
}
```

VBA Declaration

```
Declare Function RxReadResponse Lib "CDLL" (ByRef rxRead As String) As String
```

VBA Button Click

```
Sub Button2_EventClick()
Dim This As Object : Set This = Button2

    Dim s

    s = RxReadResponse

    EditBox6.Text = s


End Sub
```

The Returned String

```
0FB34CB45AB24BB45A4CB45AB24BB45A
```

Desired Outcome in VBA

```
s(0) = OF
s(1) = B3
s(2) = 4C
     .
     .
     .
s(16) = 5A
```

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: What have you tested? I see you pass a string but don't return a string, even though you declare it as returning a string. And do you mean `s(0)=0F, s(1)=B3` as you now write all `s(0)=...`.

Comment: In unsure what you mean by " what have you tested?" but the code above in the VBA code calls RxReadResponse  and the char* Response is created in the c dll and and passed back to the VBA. This is the assigned to the s variable and output as a string in the edit box. The S(0) stuff was my attempt at showing how i would like to be able to retrieve the data and insert it into an array in VBA     For Each item In s
    s(i) = item
Next

Comment: `s = RxReadResponse` seems wrong as the function is declared as taking a string, returning nothing, so should be `RxReadResponse s`. I don't see storage allocated in the function for the response and I don't see storage passed from VBA. Hence my question if you have tested it.

Comment: Oh sorry i get you now the code above works once the button is clicked the editbox is populated with the string above that works fine and tested...the function in the c dll takes a pointer to a char so by using  {s = RxReadResponse }the variable s is assigned to the function pointer

Comment: It seems that VBA is helpful here, but I still feel you do it the wrong way. (Don't use the word "function pointer" here. It means something completely different!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA can directly assign a `String` to a byte array. If the dll call is returning the correct string, just re-assign it.

```
Private Sub Example()
    Dim returned As String
    returned = "0FB34CB45AB24BB45A4CB45AB24BB45A"
    Dim cast() As Byte
    cast = returned
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(cast)
        Debug.Print cast(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that you might have to check to see if the marshaller converted the ASCII return to wide characters, but if that's the case, you can either call `StrConv` to convert it back or simply skip every other index in the byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to an old project of mine, I did the following (translated a  bit to your project).

in C:

```
char * __stdcall RxReadResponse(char* Response)
{
    //....
    return Response;
}
```

In VBA:

```
Declare Function RxReadResponse Lib "CDLL" ( _
        ByVal Response As String _
) As String

Sub Button2_EventClick()
    Dim s As String
    s = String(256, vbNullChar) 'string (storage) of 256 null chars

    s = RxReadResponse (s)
    '....
End Sub
```

I hope this can help you in the VBA part.

As for the C part, you now return a string but it seems you want to return the raw bytes. You can do that by just placing `TempChar` in `Response[i]`, without using `sprintf`. Just see `Response` as a buffer for bytes, not as a VBA String type.

Comment: thanks for the help i'll try it in the morning and if it work i'll mark as answered thanks again